# How do I delete a row of indexes with the starting and ending index in a dataframe(python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop, pandas-loc

For example:

INDEX        FRUIT

0:        "banana"

1:       "apple"

2:       "donut"

3:       "pizza"

4:       "noodles"

5:       "ice-cream"

6:       "grapefruit"

Usually, in order to drop rows 2-5 inclusive, I use *drop.(df.index[[2,3,4,5]])* However, for the project I'm doing, the dataframe is much larger and I would have to list out all the indexes to drop a lot of rows, which is really inefficient and time-consuming. Is there a quicker and shorter way to just drop the rows using only the start and end index (in this case 2 and 5). Btw, my indexes are the default one, starting from 0, 1, 2 …

Is there a line of code or way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: like `star=2, end=5, df.drop(range(start,end+1))`?

Comment: Please describe how the index is built , what libraries you use and their versions and the python version

Answer (score 2):

- you can use `df.drop(df.index[x:y])` here x is inclusive and y is exclusive, so it will delete the rows which start index from x and end index y-1

```py
start = 2
end = 5
df.drop(df.index[start:end+1])`
```

- The above code will drop rows 2-5 inclusive.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Can also;

```
df.drop(df.loc[2:5].index, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df.drop(df.iloc[2:6].index, inplace=True)
```

`df.iloc[range].index` and `df.loc[range]` selects the index needed. Please remember `.iloc` operates like python `range(start, range)`, it excluded the last index. If using it you have to go `range(start, range+1)`

Comment: Did this help? Happy to assist further if needed